# Windows kernel: cómo escribir sobre memoria RX de usermode?

Tags: c, windows

Estoy escribiendo un driver para Windows 10, y quiero hacer esto:

```
unsigned int* some_ptr = ...;
*some_ptr = 0;
```

Pero `some_ptr` apunta a memoria de usuario que es read/execute (*no* write), y por tanto, no puedo. Mi código se ejecuta en el contexto de un proceso que se comunica con el driver mediante IOCTL, y el proceso que tengo que modificar es ese mismo.

Es decir, necesito uno de estos:

- Modificar los permisos de página donde `some_ptr` apunta, para poder escribir (hacerlo desde usermode **no** es una opción, en este caso)
- Obtener un mapping diferente de la memoria física con diferentes permisos (es decir, para poder escribir por encima)

Sin embargo, no sé cómo hacer esas dos opciones. Parece que `NtProtectVirtualMemory` no está disponible para drivers, y no sé qué hacer.

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!, ¿Has intentado algo de lo que preguntas?, recuerda agregar un [mcve].

Comment: @Jorgesys Gracias! No he intentado nada de lo que pregunto, porque no sé ni por dónde empezar. No sé siquiera si esto es posible desde el kernel, y buscando en Google no encuentro nada. Mi ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable es el código que he enseñado, `*some_ptr = 0;`. Es exactamente lo que quiero hacer, pero sin la restricción de los permisos de página, que no sé cambiar. Qué me sugerirías cambiar?

Comment: revisa esto hermano: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913145.aspx te dará un bonito panorama

Comment: @fredyfx un enlace genérico a una página de inicio no me soluciona nada; no necesito una introducción a la programación en kernel sino que tengo un problema específico, descrito en la pregunta más arriba. Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: Me gustaría hermano, desconozco la respuesta a tu pregunta, sin embargo ese enlace fue algo que encontré y pensé que te sería de utilidad. Saludos :D

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Sería bueno que compartas el código completo de tu driver, explicar de qué trata o qué se quiere lograr, qué parte del kernel o qué dll están actuando sobre dicha memoria. Quizás se resuelva ejecutando peticiones al kernel o en última instancia editando kernel de manera hexadecimal (es de código cerrado) para que pueda ejecutar tu driver.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft dice que a partir de Windows 8 se puede acceder a la drección de la función con `MmGetSystemRoutineAddress()`. Tengo un libro sobre drivers con un ejemplo de uso de esa función y en el Apimonitor de Rohitab también está para poder hookear.